# C- print line and line underneath from text file

Tags: c

I have a text file like this:

> Name: Vincent
>
> Age: 21
>
> Name: Herman
>
> Age: 22
>
> Name: Hendrik
>
> Age: 42

The program asks a name and must print the name from the txt file with the age of the person. I only can print the name, but can't print the age.

This is my program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *bestand;
    char pers[32];
    char tekens[500];

    bestand = fopen("Bestand.txt", "r");

    printf("Van welke persoon wilt u de leeftijd weten?");
    gets(pers);

    while (fgets(tekens,500, bestand)!=NULL)
    {
        if (strstr(tekens, pers) != NULL)                  
        {
            printf(tekens);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: gets is dangerous. use fgets instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you read about structures, arrays and how to split strings into tokens ([`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) might help with that).

Then to solve your problem, I suggest you read the data of the file into an array of structures first. After that ask the user to input the name, and search through the array for the correct structure and then print the name and age from the structure.

Also, you need to find out some way of doing case-independent string comparison, for example if the name in the file is `Hendrik` but the user inputs `hendrik`.

Answer (score 0):

Each record is 2 lines, so read 2 lines each loop.

There are many ways to parse each line.  `sscanf()` used here.

```
char pers[32+1];
char teken1[500];
char teken2[500];

fgets(pers, sizeof pers, stdin);
pers[strcspn(pers, "\n")] = '\0'; // Get rid of potential trailing \n
...
while (fgets(teken1, sizeof teken1, bestand)  && fgets(teken2, sizeof teken2, bestand)) {
  char name[32];
  unsigned age;
  if (1 != sscanf(teken1, "Name: %31s", name)) break;  // invalid name
  if (1 != sscanf(teken2, "Age: %u", &age)) break;      // invalid age
  if (strcmp(pers, name) == 0) {
    printf("%s %u\n", name, age);
  }
}
```

Strongly recommend against `printf(tekens);`.  Should a file contain a line with a `'%'`, then `printf(tekens);` will try to reference non-existent parameters.  Better to use `fputs(tekens, stdout);`

As [@Raghu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589026/raghu-srikanth-reddy) commented, do not use `gets()`.  It has no limit on user input and is not standard on C11 compilers.

Additional code could look for 1) extra garbage on a line, 2) reasonable name content (all letters or "-'") 3) reasonable age 4) spaces in name 5) case insensitivity